# How to access the event handler from the class to use in the Form

Tags: c#

I have a class that inherit from DataGridView and I have a EventArgs same as code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace MyTest
{
    class Test1:System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    {
        private void Test1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Click");

        }

    }
}
```

Then I have a form and I want to use the Test1 in my form. So I drag Test1 from Toolbox to my form.What I want is when I run my form and click on Test1 it will show the message "CellMousClick" but when I run my form it doesn't show anything.Thanks

Comment: Is that event handler bound to the event of the DataGridView? I mean: CellMouseClick += Test1_CellMouseClick;

Comment: It's not necessary to derive a new class from `DataGridView` just to have a handler for `CellClick` nor to have an explicit override for `OnCellClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constructor in the Test1 class and attach an event handler, e.g.:

```
public Test1()
{
  this.CellMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.Test1_Click);
}
```